# Why does Vue.js not update variables inside data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

## Can't update variables inside data in Vue

I'm creating a project using Vue 3 as frontend.

In Dashboard.vue, a `GET` request will be sent to backend with token in header, in order to let the backend identify user's identity, then Vue will receive the response with a json including info like this: `{'uid': 'xxx', 'username': 'xxx'}`.

My Dashboard.vue:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            uid: '',
            username: '',
            temp: {},
            loaded: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        require_get(url) {
            var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'token': token,
                }
            };
            var _url = 'user/dashboard/' + url;
            axios.get(_url, config)
            .then(response => {
                this.temp = response.data;
            })
        },
        get_user_info() {
            this.require_get('info');
            this.uid = this.temp['username']; 
            this.username = this.temp['username'];
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.get_user_info();
    }
}
</script>
```

In this way, `uid` and `username` cannot be updated correctly.

For debugging, when I add `console.log(this.uid)` at the end of `get_user_info()` like this:

```
//...
this.require_get('info');
this.uid = this.temp['username']; 
this.username = this.temp['username'];
console.log(this.temp['uid']);
```

I get a `undefined`. But when I add `console.log(this.uid)` at the end of `require.get()` like this:

```
//...
.then(response => {
                this.temp = response.data;
                console.log(this.temp['uid]);
            })
```

The output shows that variable `uid` has already been updated at this moment.

After testing, I found that I can correctly update `uid` and `username` as long as I put

```
this.uid = this.temp['username']; 
this.username = this.temp['username'];
```

inside `require_get()`.
Why is that? And how can I manage to update these variables with these two codes staying in `get_user_info()`?

## Update

I changed my codes into"

```
    methods: {
        async require_get(url) {
            var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'token': token,
                }
            };
            var _url = 'user/dashboard/' + url;
            axios.get(_url, config)
            .then(response => {
                return response.data;
            })
        },
        async get_user_info() {
            let info = await this.require_get('info');
            console.log(info);
            this.uid = info['username']; 
            this.username = info['username'];
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.get_user_info('info');
    }
```

and the output of `console.log(info)` is still `undefined`, now I don't understand...

Comment: Just a question, why are you using Options API in Vue 3?

Comment: In short: asynchronous execution. In your `require_get` function, you update `temp` in the `.then()` callback, which is called when the Promise has _resolved_. In `get_user_info`, you are calling `require_get` and then immediately trying to read the data. Because it is fetched asynchronously, it is not yet present and you get `undefined`.

Comment: Have you studied anything of asynchronous execution and Promises? (Honest question, not being snarky)

Comment: Well I guessed asynchronous execution causes the problem, but how can I fix this? Or is there another possibility that `this.` in `this.temp` in my `require_get()` doesn't refer to `data`?

Comment: Well I think I can use the return value to get rid of asynchronous execution. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Make `require_get` an async function and return the data instead of using `this.temp`. Then make `get_user_info` an async function as well, `await` the call of `require_get`, and assign `this.uid` and `this.username` to the returned data. You could also use do the assignment in a `.then()` callback on the call of `require_get`, of you prefer that to `async`/`await`.

Comment: In your updated code, you are not returning the promise: `return axios.get(_url, config)...`

Comment: You have to await also the request call. I would make it as follows: `const result = await axios.get(_url, config); return result.data;`.

Comment: `Well I think I can use the return value to get rid of asynchronous execution.` Note: if something is inherently asynchronous (such as a network request), you cannot simply "get rid of it". You either block until it is finished (bad) or you handle it asynchronously.

Comment: I get it. That's really considerate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is asynchronous execution.

In `require_get`, you update `this.temp` in the `.then()` callback, which is only called when the Promise has *resolved*. In `get_user_info`, you are calling `require_get` and then *immediately* (synchronously) trying to read the data. Because it is fetched and set asynchronously, it is not yet present and you get `undefined`.

To fix it, make `require_get` an async function and return the data instead of using `this.temp`. Then make `get_user_info` an async function as well, await the call of `require_get`, and assign `this.uid` and `this.username` to the returned data.

You could also use `.then()` if you prefer that to async/await. I have included examples for both.

I assume that `this.uid = data['username']` was meant to be `this.uid = data['uid']`, so changed that too.

**With async/await**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            uid: '',
            username: '',
            loaded: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async require_get(url) {
            var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'token': token,
                }
            };
            var _url = 'user/dashboard/' + url;
            var response = await axios.get(_url, config);
            return response.data;
        },
        async get_user_info() {
            var data = await this.require_get('info');
            this.uid = data['uid']; 
            this.username = data['username'];
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.get_user_info();
    }
}
```

**With `.then()`**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            uid: '',
            username: '',
            loaded: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        require_get(url) {
            var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'token': token,
                }
            };
            var _url = 'user/dashboard/' + url;
            return axios.get(_url, config).then((response) => response.data);
        },
        get_user_info() {
            this.require_get('info').then((data) => {
                this.uid = data['uid']; 
                this.username = data['username'];
            });
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.get_user_info();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, it works! Really detailed and helpful :)